# Remove points that are close to a border when building a grid

Tags: r, sf, borders

I want to remove the points that are close to a boarder when building a grid, i am using the sf library from R.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)


shp <- getData('GADM', country = 'aut', level = 0) %>% st_as_sf()


grid <- st_make_grid(shp, n=c(25, 25), 
                     what = "centers", 
                     square=TRUE) %>% st_intersection(shp)  

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shp) +
  geom_sf(data = grid, col ="red")
```

Example of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute distance from grid points to shape border. Border is converted to linear geometry because distance from point to polygon for points inside polygon=0.

```
> d = st_distance(grid, st_cast(shp,"MULTILINESTRING"))
```

Select grid points further than 10km from border:

```
> gridin2 = grid[d[,1]>units::set_units(10,km)]
```

Gives:

```
> plot(shp$geometry)
> plot(gridin2,add=TRUE)
```

You could also do it by a negative buffer and an intersection, but `st_buffer` would need a coordinate transformation first to work in real units rather than degrees. The `st_distance` approach works in proper distances.

[image]